# Reading and Passing Excel Filename with Pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I want to read excel file with Pandas, delete the header row and the first column and write the resultant data in an excel file with the same name. I want to do it for all the excel files in a folder. I have written the code for data reading and writing but having trouble with saving the data in a file with the same name. The code I have written is like this-

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import os
for filename in os.listdir ('./'):
    if filename.endswith ('.xlsx'):
        df = pd.read_excel ('new.xlsx', skiprows=1)
        df.drop (df.columns [0], axis=1, inplace=True)
        df.to_csv ('new.csv', index=False)
```

How can I automate my code for all the excel files in the same folder?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use variable `filename` in function `read_excel` and then create new file names by `format` and for remove first column is possible use [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) - select all columns without first:

```
for filename in os.listdir ('./'):
    if filename.endswith ('.xlsx'):
        df = pd.read_excel (filename, skiprows=1)
        df.iloc[:, 1:].to_csv('new_{}.csv'.format(filename), index=False)
```

Another solution with `glob`, there is possible specify extensions:

```
import glob

for filename in glob.glob('./*.xlsx'):
    df = pd.read_excel (filename, skiprows=1)
    df.iloc[:, 1:].to_csv('new_{}.csv'.format(filename), index=False)   
    #python 3.6+    
    #df.iloc[:, 1:].to_csv (f'new_{filename}.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: great ans as always, BTW by any chance do you know any doc where one can find out abbreviations like `f''` for `format`, `r''` for regex, etc.

Comment: @meW - pure python is not easy for me, try ask it jpp :)

Comment: Okay will check with him.

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks! Although, it is taking the whole name, including the .xlsx suffix, thus the name is being generated like new.xlsx.csv

Comment: @Soelem Aafnan Yeham so add `[:-5]` like `df.iloc[:, 1:].to_csv('new_{}.csv'.format(filename[:-5]), index=False)`  for remove last 5 letters or use `df.iloc[:, 1:].to_csv('new_{}.csv'.format(os.path.splitext(filename)[0])), index=False)`

Answer (score 0):

Try Below for reading multiple files as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

# Read multiple files into one dataframe along with pandas `concat`
# if you have path defined like `/home/data/` then you can use `/home/data/*.xlsx` otherwise you directly mention the path.

df = pd.concat([pd.read_excel(files, sep=',', index=False, skiprows=1) for files in glob.glob("/home/data/*.xlsx")])
```

**Alternative:**
Read multiple files into one dataframe

```
all_Files = glob.glob('/home/data/*.xlsx')

df = pd.concat((pd.read_excel(files, sep=',', index=False, skiprows=1) for files in all_Files))
```